# Can I override SSH config based on the *client* hostname?

Tags: linux, ssh

I sync my SSH config across all my computers. One of my computers is in a specific environment where some SSH connections need a jumphost. I can't just add that setting to my SSH config, since that would break on all my other computers.

Is it possible to conditionally apply that setting in my SSH configuration based on the current hostname? I'm imagining something like:

```
Host *.company.com
  User yhfe312

If ClientHostname == "special-hostname"
  Host *.company.com
    ProxyJump jumphost.example.com
```

---

I have tried a workaround involving the `Include` keyword. In my main SSH config I add this to the end:

```
Include special-hostname
```

Then in `~/.ssh/special-hostname` I add:

```
Host *.company.com
  ProxyJump jumphost.example.com
```

But it's not having any effect, the jumphost isn't being used unless I specify it manually in the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for OpenSSH[1] there's the `Match` *keyword* which supports running commands in shell through the *criteria* `exec`. If the command specified in `exec` has an exit code of `0` then that condition has matched, otherwise failed.

The shell command to compare against the local hostname and exit with `0` on exact match:

```shell
test "conditionhostname" = "$(cat /etc/hostname)"
```

Due to very basic quotation rules inside the config, save it as a file with executable permission +x set, for example at `~/.ssh/ishostname.sh`. This will compare the first passed argument against the local hostname:

```shell
#!/bin/sh
test "$1" = "$(cat /etc/hostname)"
```

Now this can be used as an exec condition in the SSH config:

```
Match exec="~/.ssh/ishostname.sh 'special-hostname'"
    # My directives for 'special-hostname' follow below...
```

[1]: Read the OpenSSH client config manual with `man ssh_config`. Technically, `Match` is a superset of `Host` with more options.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I attempted in the question worked, I just had to place the `Include` keyword at the very top of `.ssh/config`. I have no idea why that was necessary, but it worked.

So to summarize, to override SSH configuration only on the current host, add a line like `Include myhostname` at the top of `.ssh/config`, where "myhostname" is the hostname of your current computer. Create a file called `.ssh/myhostname` where you place config overrides. On other machines, that file won't exist and SSH will silently ignore it.